# Most efficient XAML UI element for dumping "standard output"

Tags: xaml, uwp

As per the title, what is the most efficient way to make use available XAML UI elements to display a lot of [selectable, non-modifiable] texts being appended regularly? Think of dumping out logging information or big HTML page as they are downloaded.

The `TextBox` does not seem to be very efficient since the only way to change the text is to set its `Text` property which is a `Platform::String`. There is no efficient way to append `Platform::String` repeatedly since I believe that the `Platform::String(const wchar_t *)` constructor copies the input string internally so even if I try to use string buffer, it doesn't help.

As for the other text control `RichEditBox`, I have no idea how to use it within a `DataTemplate`. (I need the control to be elements of a `ListView`.)

Comment: Add lines to an observablecollection bound to an itemscontrol. Prune it when it gets too big. *"I need the control to be elements of a ListView"* -- not sure what you're getting at there; can you clarify?

Comment: @Ed I mean I need a TextBox for each items in a list. That is putting TextBox in ListViewItem and use data binding.

Comment: So each of these text boxes gets an arbitrary number of log lines added to it? I missed that the text needs to be selectable. I think you may be stuck.

Comment: @Ed Yes, there might be lots of line on the one hand and there might be one single *very long* line on the other extreme.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the logs as items of a `ListView` or `ItemsControl` and display each as simple `TextBlock` with selectability:

```
<TextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" ... />
```

This is the most efficient approach you can get, as the list provides virtualization and `TextBlock` has minimal overhead as compared to `TextBlock` and `RichEditBox` and is read-only.

Comment: @An Hoa If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.